# jQuery not parsing json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a website and partner provide me this link https://www.fundingoptions.com/partner/integration/

I checked there is something related with oEmbed, but I not familiar with it.

This url `https://www.fundingoptions.com/oembed/?affid=10` is returning json which I was parsing like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajax({
    cache: true,
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'json/data.json',
    data: { get_param: 'value' },
    dataType:'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var names = data
        $('#json').html(data.html);
    }
  });

});
```

But it does not work anymore, I am stuck now :(.

Comment: What does "not working" mean, exactly? What happens? Do you get errors in the browser's dev console?

Comment: Is there a missing semicolon at the end of the line "var names = data"? Also, should "json/data.json" be the link you mentioned, "https://www.fundingoptions.com/oembed/?affid=10" instead?

Comment: @Hiphop03199 In my opinion they *should* have a semicolon but it's perfectly fine if they don't in this case.

Comment: I learn something new every day- I know javascript is pretty lenient with semicolons, but I hadn't known that would work. Thanks

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies guys ..
here how its looked after i integrate  
http://compareyourbusinesscosts.com/commercial-business-finance/

its need to look like widget section of this website
https://www.fundingoptions.com/partner/integration/

Comment: any lucks with the issue ?